# Generics Vs. Arraylist?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I am a little confused regarding ArrayLists and generics, for instance, in the program below when I declared, `Gen<Integer>iOb=new Gen<Integer>(88);` it declared a generic type of Integer correct? However, if I declare an arraylist in the same fashion? In the case of an arraylist, it is the type that is in angle brackets, however, researching generics, it says that the type in the angle brackets is the generic type? How do I know if its an arraylist of a class type or a generic?

```
//A simple generic class 
//Here, T is a type parameter that
///will be replaced by a real type
//when an object of type gen is created
class Gen<T> {
    T ob;//declare an object of type T

    //Pass the constructor a refernce to
    //an object of type T 
    Gen(T o) {
        ob = o;
    }

    //return ob
    T getob() {
        return ob;
    }

    //show type of t
    void showType() {
        System.out.println("Type of T is " + ob.getClass().getName());
    }
}

class GenDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a gen reference for integers
        Gen<Integer> iOb;
        //Create a Gen<Integer>Object and assign its 
        //reference to iob, notice the use  of autoboxing
        //to encapsulate the value 88 within an integer object 
        iOb = new Gen<Integer>(88);

        //show the type off data used by iob 
        iOb.showType();
        //get the value in Iob notice that no cast is needed
        int v = iOb.getob();
        System.out.println("Value: " + v);
        System.out.println();
        //create a gen object for strings
        Gen<String> strOb = new Gen<String>("Generic Test");
        //show the type of data 
        strOb.showType();
        //get the value of strOb, again notice that no cast is needed 
        String str = strOb.getob();
        System.out.println("Value  :" + str);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `ArrayList` in this code. ArrayList is a class. A generic class. Just like `Gen`. What is exactly troubling you?

Comment: I understand that there is not arraylist in this code, but an arraylist and a generic is declared in the same exact way, how do I know if its a generic or an ArrayList of type Gen?

Comment: What is "a generic" for you? Have you read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/?

Comment: [*The* tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/simple.html) calls `Gen<T>` a generic type, `T` a type argument, and `Gen<Integer>` a parameterized type.

Comment: @jozencl, Sounds like, when you say "generic type", you are talking about what everybody else calls a _raw_ type.  `ArrayList<T>` is a generic type, and `ArrayList` is a raw type.  You can declare raw types in your code (e.g., you can declare a variable that refers to an `ArrayList` without saying an `ArrayList` of what, but you'll have to deal with a boat load of compiler warnings if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I declared, `Gen<Integer> iOb = new Gen(88);` it declared a generic type of Integer correct?

This is incorrect.  You are declaring/creating an `Gen` object, which holds a `T extends Object`.  Inside `Gen` code, you can only use functions that are allowed to be used on an `Object`, such as `getClass()`.

The Java Compiler remembers that `iOb` will reference a `Gen` object that *must* hold an `Integer` object, and will generate automatic type casting on the return value of `getob()` ...

```
int v=iOb.getob();
```

Is interpreted by the compiler as if the following was written:

```
int v = (Integer) iObj.getob();
```

Where `getob()` is considered to just return an `Object`.  Note that this is a compile-time transformation as a convenience for the programmer.

> However, if I declare an arraylist in the same fashion? In the case of an arraylist, it is the type that is in angle brackets, however, researching generics, it says that the type in the angle brackets is the generic type? How do I know if its an arraylist of a class type or a generic???

`class SomeClass<T> { ... }` declares a generic type.  The part between the angle brackets is the "type argument(s)" for the generic class.

When the generic class used as a type for a variable, it is considered a specialization of the the generic class, and type argument(s) could be a concrete class, an interface, or another generic class.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing the concepts of a ***generic type*** and a ***type parameter***.

Given your class:

```
class Gen<T> {
    // ...
}
```

`Gen` is a generic class (a specific kind of generic type) because it is declared to have at least one type parameter, in this case `T`.  When you instantiate `Gen`, and sometimes in other cases, you provide a type expression that is bound to `T`:

```
Gen<?> gen = new Gen<String>();
```

The type expressions given (`?` and `String`) are typically also called "type parameters", just like the `T` in class `Gen`'s definition.  *Specific* type parameters may be formed from generic classes (example: `List<String>` in `Gen<List<String>>`), but "generic class" is not a synonym for "type parameter".

`ArrayList` is just the same.  It is a generic class with one type parameter.  Specific declarations provide type expressions to serve as the values of those type parameters:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

There, `List<E>` and `ArrayList<E>` are generic types; the latter is specifically a generic class.  The `Integer` on both sides is the type parameter applying to the declaration of `list` and the instantiation of `ArrayList`; it is not referred to as a "generic class" in this context or any other.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is worded kind of strange, but I'll give it a shot.  Generics are used for type safety, ESPECIALLY for collections.  If you were to declare an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList a= new ArrayList();
```

then you could put any kind of object you wanted in to the ArrayList.  That's very dangerous since when you're retrieving objects from the list you'll need to know what kind of object you will be retrieving from the list.  You wouldn't want to pull a cat object into a person reference! Cats aren't people!  That's where generics come in.  Declaring your ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<People> p= new ArrayList<People>();
```

allows you to have type safety.  No more problems with those pesky Cat objects getting in to your people array!

As for this:

```
//get the value in Iob notice that no cast is needed

int v = iOb.getob();
```

You seem to be getting confused with unboxing.  It has nothing to do with Generics.  I recommend you look up autboxing and unboxing.

finally:

```
  //get the value of strOb, again notice that no cast is needed

    String str = strOb.getob();
```

I don't see what you don't understand here.  Strings are objects.  You put a String object in and you pulled a String object out.

I also recommend creating a simple java object, say a person, so you can create a generic with your Gen class, say String, and attempt to put a Person object in.  See what errors it gives.

Answer (score 1):

First, we should clear up some terms. From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

> In a nutshell, generics enable types (classes and interfaces) to be parameters when defining classes, interfaces and methods. Much like the more familiar formal parameters used in method declarations, type parameters provide a way for you to re-use the same code with different inputs. The difference is that the inputs to formal parameters are values, while the inputs to type parameters are types.

So when you did `Gen<Integer>iOb=new Gen<Integer>(88);`, a `Gen` class was made of type `Gen` but with generic type parameter `Integer`. `Gen` is a generic class because the class header contains a generic type parameter `<T>`. However, Arraylists are also generic classes because they are not restricted to one type as you can tell from the declaration. When declaring a Arraylist, you can do a type declaration the same way you do so for your Gen class. Ex: `Arraylist<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Arraylists do have a raw type implementation which does require not a type parameter in the declaration. Ex: `Arraylist list = new Arraylist();` But this is not recommended and Java will actually give you a warning if you declare arraylists this way, advising you to parameterize the arraylist.

In conclusion, a generic type is a generic class or interface that is parameterized over types (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html). So your `Gen` class and the built-in `Arraylist` class of Java are both generic types.